# Calculate $F(0)$, $F'(0)$ and $F''(x)$

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

$$F(x)= \int_0^x \cos(t^2) \,\mathrm dt$$

Do I plug in $F(0)$ so that $\int_0^0$ and then solve the integral? Doesn't this just mean that my integral will equal $0$?

And for $F'(0)$ since  $F'(x)$=$f(x)$ I should take the derivative of $\cos(t^2)$ which is $-2x\sin x(x^2)$ and then solve for $x=0$ but this is $0$ as well and I am supposed to get the answer $F'(0)=1$.

Comment: $F(0) = 0$ as you discuss.  $F'(x) = f(x) = \cos x^2, F'(0) = f(0) = \cos  0 = 1, F''(x) = f'(x) = 2x\sin x^2 = 0$

Comment: @DougM May I just ask why $2xsinx^2$ isn't negative?

Comment: it could be when for certain values of $x.$ i.e. $x = 2$  But at $x=0, 2\cdot 0\cdot \sin 0 = 0$

Comment: I was thinking about that the derivative of $cosx$ is $-sinx$ but the answer here is not $-2xsinx^2$

Comment: indeed, I must have been going to fast.  good catch.

Comment: Although in our answer key the answer is not negative either..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For #2, the rule is $\displaystyle F'(x) = \frac d{dx} \int_0^{a(x)} f(t)\, dt = f(a(x)) \cdot \frac d{dx} a(x)$.

In your case, $a(x) = x$ and $f(t) = \cos (t^2)$.

Comment: So I should just get $cos(x^2)$?

Comment: @J.Se, yes.  That's $F'(x)$.  Then getting $F'(0)$ and $F''(x)$ are straightforward from there.

Comment: Instead of stating an arbitrary rule I think it would be better to show how all this is connected to the FTC. If the next time there's $b(x)$ instead of zero OP won't be able to apply the rule.

Answer (score 0):

1) Yes, $\int_0^0=0$ by definition (in elementary courses).
2) Please differentiate correctly the cosine... **Anyway**: the derivative of $\cos (t^2)$ is unnecessary for your purposes.

Comment: cosine isn't supposed to be differentiated for 2.

Comment: Sure, but @J.Se wrote a false identity.

Comment: I noticed, but "please differentiate correctly the cosine" suggests that the cosine needs to be differentiated, which it doesn't for $F'(0)$.